# python: testing specific functions in unit test?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I already know how to test specific classes in python's unittest framework. However, I am having trouble testing specific functions. Here is what I use to select classes that I want to get tested:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_classes_to_run = [Class1, Class2, Class3]

    loader = unittest.TestLoader()

    suites_list = []
    for test_class in test_classes_to_run:
        suite = loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(test_class)
        suites_list.append(suite)

    big_suite = unittest.TestSuite(suites_list)

    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    results = runner.run(big_suite)
```

So I tried selecting a specific function doing:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    testing_class = Class1
    test_classes_to_run = [Class1.function1]

    loader = unittest.TestLoader()

    suites_list = []
    for test_class in test_classes_to_run:
        suite = loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(test_class)
        suites_list.append(suite)

    big_suite = unittest.TestSuite(suites_list)

    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    results = runner.run(big_suite)
```

but I get the following error:

> TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
unittest.TestLoader.loadTestsFromName('Path.to.Class1.test_function1')
```

From the [documentation of the unittest module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.loadTestsFromName):

> For example, if you have a module SampleTests containing a
>   TestCase-derived class SampleTestCase with three test methods
>   (test_one(), test_two(), and test_three()), the specifier
>   'SampleTests.SampleTestCase' would cause this method to return a suite
>   which will run all three test methods. Using the specifier
>   'SampleTests.SampleTestCase.test_two' would cause it to return a test
>   suite which will run only the test_two() test method. The specifier
>   can refer to modules and packages which have not been imported; they
>   will be imported as a side-effect.